# How to install DTBs overlays on Ubuntu Сore 20?

Tags: ubuntu

How to enable PWM device? There is no `/sys/class/pwm/` devices. I did not find dts compiler or overlay config. Point to documentation of enabling GPIO devices: hardware pwm, spi, i2c etc.

Comment: Where did you look for the dts compiler or overlay?

Comment: @Seamus on armbian. but Pi not supported in that distro. I know  about raspios etc. but searching way to enable PWM, I2C etc right way on Core.